# Using Woocommerce get_price() in header

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-theming

How do i use WC_Product Methods outside the loop.

I need to output the price of my product and SKU in the header of my theme.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `$product` object for a particular product product using it's product ID.

```
$product_id = 99;
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
echo $product->get_price_html();
```